# Improving an algorithm for substring search when reading ZIP files

Tags: ruby, algorithm, zip, substring

So I have a ZIP reader library, and I read ZIP files by first figuring out where the EOCD record is (the standard way "from the tail"). I have to look for a pattern that is roughly this:

`4byte_magic_number, fixed_n_bytes, 2_bytes_of_comment_size, comment`

The bytesize of `comment` is provided in the `2_bytes_of_comment_size`. Just scanning for the magic number is insufficient, because I eager-read a substantial portion at the tail of the file - basically the maximum size the ZIP EOCD record can be, and then look for this pattern in there.

So far, I came up with this

```
def locate_eocd_signature(in_str)
  # We have to scan from the _very_ tail. We read the very minimum size
  # the EOCD record can have (up to and including the comment size), using
  # a sliding window. Once our end offset matches the comment size we found our
  # EOCD marker.
  eocd_signature_int = 0x06054b50
  unpack_pattern = 'VvvvvVVv'
  minimum_record_size = 22
  end_location = minimum_record_size * -1
  loop do
    # If the window is nil, we have rolled off the start of the string, nothing to do here.
    # We use negative values because if we used positive slice indices
    # we would have to detect the rollover ourselves
    break unless window = in_str[end_location, minimum_record_size]

    window_location = in_str.bytesize + end_location
    unpacked = window.unpack(unpack_pattern)

    # If we found the signature, pick up the comment size, and check if the size of the window
    # plus that comment size is where we are in the string. If we are - bingo.
    if unpacked[0] == 0x06054b50 && comment_size = unpacked[-1] 
      assumed_eocd_location = in_str.bytesize - comment_size - minimum_record_size
      # if the comment size is where we should be at - we found our EOCD
      return assumed_eocd_location if assumed_eocd_location == window_location
    end

    end_location -= 1 # Shift the window back, by one byte, and try again.
  end
end
```

but it just screams *ugly* at me. Is there a better way to do something like this? Is there a `pack` specifier that says "all the bytes in binary until the the end of the string" that I do not know of? Then I could tack that onto the end of the pack specifier for example... A bit at loss here.

Comment: Maybe you could use a regular expression, but if you're trying to avoid ugly that's probably the wrong way to steer. One way to clean this up is to move your constants into actual constants and encapsulate this inside a class or module. Also use your constants instead of sprinkling the same magical numbers through your code.

Comment: I am using just enough constants in the [module](https://github.com/WeTransfer/zip_tricks/blob/master/lib/zip_tricks/file_reader.rb) it is coming from :-) but point taken. Regexes do seem a passing application in this case actually...

Comment: Just watch that you don't make a Regular Expression of Death. [It can happen to the best of us](http://stackstatus.net/post/147710624694/outage-postmortem-july-20-2016).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I opted for the following optimization. First, I made a method for finding all the indices of a given substring in a string - there is no stdlib builtin for this.

```
def all_indices_of_substr_in_str(of_substring, in_string)
  last_i = 0
  found_at_indices = []
  while last_i = in_string.index(of_substring, last_i)
    found_at_indices << last_i
    last_i += of_substring.bytesize
  end
  found_at_indices
end
```

Then, we use it to "latch" onto the offsets in our buffer where our signature was found.

```
def locate_eocd_signature(in_str)
  eocd_signature = 0x06054b50
  eocd_signature_str = [eocd_signature].pack('V')
  unpack_pattern = 'VvvvvVVv'
  minimum_record_size = 22
  str_size = in_str.bytesize
  indices = all_indices_of_substr_in_str(eocd_signature_str, in_str)
  indices.each do |check_at|
    maybe_record = in_str[check_at..str_size]
    # If the record is smaller than the minimum - we will never recover anything
    break if maybe_record.bytesize < minimum_record_size
    # Now we check if the record ends with the combination
    # of the comment size and an arbitrary byte string of that size.
    # If it does - we found our match
    *_unused, comment_size = maybe_record.unpack(unpack_pattern)
    if (maybe_record.bytesize - minimum_record_size) == comment_size
      return check_at # Found the EOCD marker location
    end
  end
  # If we haven't caught anything, return nil deliberately instead of returning the last statement
  nil
end
```